# Using "perceive" with the senses

Tags: verbs

Can one **perceive** an odour or **smell** it?

> I perceive something is smelling.
>
> I smell something.

Comment: Perceive a smell. Smell something.

Answer (score 2):

> I Perceive something is smelling.

*Perceive* essentially means your senses are registering something.  You may or may not know if your senses are fooling you but you know what they are telling you.  It also does not relate to your thoughts, opinions, or *interpretation* of your senses - *think* or *believe* is better in that case.

If you don't know where the smell is coming from, then trying to specify who/what the origin is with *something* sounds weird (but it's fine to *believe* or *think* that)- because a *perception* is typically something definite, but possibly limited. *I perceive a smell, but not sure from where* is better.